# How to migrate Oracle View to Teradata

Tags: oracle, migration, view, etl, teradata

I am working on migration project of Oracle to Teradata.

The tables have been migrated using datastage jobs.

How do I migrate Oracle Views to Teradata?

Direct script copying is not working due to SQL statements difference of both databases

Please help?

Comment: Which part(s) of the view in the Oracle view are you having issues identifying a Teradata equivalent? Can you share any part of the view definition? Many functions native to Oracle that are not ANSI standard will require a UDF in Teradata of which some may be downloaded from http://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions

Comment: DECODE (t.satisfaction, NULL, 'Not Evaluated', t.satisfaction) satisfaction, ................... error is it says satisfaction is not a data type :(

Answer (score 2):

The `DECODE()` Oracle function is available as part of the Oracle UDF Library on the Teradata Developer Exchange [Downloads](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions) section. Otherwise, you are using the DECODE function in your example in the same manner in which the ANSI `COALESCE()` function behaves:

```
COALESCE(t.satisfaction, 'Not Evaluated')
```

It should be noted that the data types of the `COALESCE()` function must be implicitly compatible or you will receive an error. Therefore, t.satisfaction would need to be at least `CHAR(13)` or `VARCHAR(13)` in order for the `COALESCE()` to evaluate. If it is not, you can explicitly cast the operand(s).

```
COALESCE(CAST(t.satisfaction AS VARCHAR(13)), 'Not Evaluated')
```

If your use of `DECODE()` includes more evaluations than what is in your example I would suggest implementing the UDF or replacing it with a more standard evaluated `CASE` statement. That being said, with Teradata 14 (or 14.1) you will find that many of the Oracle functions that are missing from Teradata will be made available as standard functions to help ease the migration path from Oracle to Teradata.